# How can I bind multiple tmux commands to one keystroke?

Tags: configuration, tmux

Specifically I'm trying to give a notification after some command was completed.  So, for example, if I reload my configuration file, I'd like to have some confirmation that it worked, which might be done something like this:

```
bind R source-file "$HOME/.tmux.conf" && display-message "Configuration reloaded."
```

*That*, however, doesn't work.  Nor do any other things I tried as ways of stringing commands together.

Comment: It works for me (tmux 1.3 on Debian squeeze) with `\;` as the separator.

Comment: Okay, I found that \; *does* work, and that is the essence of the answer I chose below.   Somehow I tested \; too quickly and determined it didn't work.  But I'm leaving this question here since it still serves to answer the question of how to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`run-shell` option](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1), but the critical thing is to separate the commands with `\;`

In this case, something like:

```
bind R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; run-shell "echo 'Reload'"
```

> **run-shell** *shell-command*
>   (alias: run)
>   Execute shell-command in the background without creating
>   a window.  After it finishes, any output to stdout is displayed in
>   copy mode.  If the command doesn't return success, the exit status is
>   also displayed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.  I haven't tested that specifically but I don't think it will work, since I tested the code in my question with \; and it just ran the second command but not the first.  And I don't know why run-shell would work but display-message wouldn't.

Comment: Okay, I've tried testing your solution and tmux keeps locking up, apparently (though not with absolute certainty) from that command.  I'll keep trying, but I'm pretty sure it won't work...

Comment: It works on tmux 1.4. Does "locking up" mean "copy mode" - that is by design...

Comment: okay, I got it to work, without locking up tmux.  That left me with the question as to why my original attempt to use \; didn't work:

Comment: bind R source-file "$HOME/.tmux.conf" \; display-message "Configuration reloaded."

Comment: Testing it again, I found it *did* work.  So somehow I screwed something up when I originally tried using \;    :p

Comment: The heart of your answer is to use \;  -- the part about run-shell is not really important, and I think for the example I gave display-message is a lot better.   So I'm choosing your answer over mine, but would you mind editing the answer so it doesn't mislead or confuse other people.   Thanks!

Comment: I have changed it: but I agree that display-message is a better approach. Edit your post and accept that, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @jasonwryan: you mean edit my answer and accept that?  No: I think I should give you the credit for pointing out that a semi-color *does* in fact work, even though somehow it failed for me the first time I tried it.  Obviously it's not a cut-and-dried situation, but since you got me to try that again, it doesn't seem right for me to take the credit.

Answer (score 4):

Just after composing my question I thought of something that might work.  I tried it and it works, you just have to put up with multiple files for your tmux configuration.

Here's the solution, specifically as it relates to reloading your configuration.  In your .tmux.conf file, put something like this:

```
bind R source-file "$HOME/.tmux/reload.tmux"
```

In the file ~/.tmux/reload.tmux put something like the following:

```
source-file "$HOME/.tmux.conf" 
display-message "Configuration reloaded."
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: This is actually the ONLY way it does work. Everything else here is just not working.

Comment: Really?... It's been a while since I tested the other approach, but I'd be surprised if tmux broke that.  If you're absolutely sure it doesn't work, then I'll test again and possibly accept this answer instead.

Comment: Yeah I apologize, the above answer really does work :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using the run-shell method puts the output into the copy buffer which requires manually clearing.  Using a intermediate configuration file adds the overhead of maintaining a second configuration file.  Combining both answers works better in my case, as I wanted the message to disappear after a short interval, similar to a pop-up dialog box in a GUI, but keep everything contained in a single file.

```
bind R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Configuration reloaded"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a patch allowing full-fledged scripting inside tmux, attaching tcl language to its internals.

http://ershov.github.io/tmux/

Also, it allows to specify as many actions as you want for 'mode' keystrokes.

Using that, your code would look like:

```
bind R tcl { source-file "$HOME/.tmux.conf" ; display-message "Configuration reloaded." }
```

or even more readable:

```
bind R tcl {
  source-file "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
  display-message "Configuration reloaded."
}
```