# tmux.conf file will not use backslash comma in lines \;

Tags: tmux

Using tmux both 1.7 and 1.8.

I see `\;` in tmux.conf files everywhere, but it fails with an error when I add it to mine.  Here is an example:

```
bind -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection \; run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | curl -d @- localhost:5482"
```

I get this error:

> /Users/user/.tmux.conf:30: usage: bind-key [-cnr] [-t key-table] key command [arguments]

Examples here:

1. [How can I bind multiple tmux commands to one keystroke?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14700/how-can-i-bind-multiple-tmux-commands-to-one-keystroke)
2. https://superuser.com/questions/562567/tmux-bind-key-and-running-shell-isnt-working

Seems to only happen when using the bind -t option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key table bindings (those made with `-t`) use a different set of commands (only movement and editing); they also do not allow `\;` to execute multiple commands.

The `copy-pipe` “mode” command (new in *tmux* 1.8) looks like it will probably be useful for your particular situation:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "curl -d @- localhost:5482"
```

You may also need to switch to `--data-binary` or `--data-urlencoded` to preserve your data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this using netcat today that is pretty dead simple.

https://github.com/base698/tmux-copy-paste-mac-osx

Here is the tmux.conf:

```
bind -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy 'y' copy-pipe 'nc localhost 5682'
bind p run-shell 'nc localhost 5683; nc localhost 5683 | tmux load-buffer -' \; paste-buffer
bind p run-shell 'nc localhost 5683; nc localhost 5683
```

Works with the mouse too in 1.8